Images not appearing in SwiftUI View
I created a custom image in Adobe Illustrator, exported the .png files to my Assets catalog, and named it Leafy. When I try to add the image to a View, it creates the frame, but the image doesn't appear. To be sure it wasn't an issue with the Image itself, I created a second project to test the .svg and .jpg formats of the image, and both of them appeared.
Here is the view I want to place the image in:
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $currentPage) {
                // Page 0: Welcome Page
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Welcome to Nutrify")
                        .font(.custom("Anek Devanagari", size: 28).weight(.medium))
                        .foregroundColor(primaryColor)
                        .padding()
                    Image("Leafy")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
                    Text("We're glad to have you here!")
                        .font(.custom("Anek Devanagari", size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        nextPage()
                    }) {
                        Text("Next")
                            .font(.custom("Anek Devanagari", size: 20).weight(.medium))
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .white)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .padding()
                            .background(buttonBackgroundColor)
                            .cornerRadius(13)
                    }
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 30)
                }
                .tag(0)
                .padding()

Here are the screenshots of the Asset Catalog and its settings, plus the preview I'm receiving:


If anyone can explain why this image is not appearing in this project but does in a separate one, it would be greatly appreciated!
Edit:
I ran the app again, and this appears to only be an issue with the preview, not the app itself. So, if anyone could provide some insight into why the preview won't display the image but the actual app does, it would be greatly appreciated!

have you considered define the bundle of the resource? Image("Leafy", bundle: .current)

@Daniyar Defining the bundle doesn't work

Does it help to add .scaledToFit() before the .frame?

Doesn't it work only in Preview or while running too? Which bundle did you provide? Is it a development cocoa pod?

@Daniyar it's just a preview issue, but very annoying because this is an onboarding page

As Preview is a separate bundle it doesn't have resources attached to your main bundle. Try to play around with the bundle argument of the Image initialiser.

@Daniyar there are other images in the Asset folder that work in preview though

Interesting. Then check which target does the view file belong to.

@Daniyar they all have the same single target that is the app

@JonGrimes20 I run your code with my own image and it works perfectly fine. Can you provide screenshot of first tab when click to Leafy image?

@JonGrimes20 i think you need work around frame instead of resizable. it might solve your problem

Did you try using xcode autocomplete for the image name? Image(.leafy) ?
